# Custom Lists and Workflow permissions

Tags: workflow, permissions, custom-list

Okay SharePoint Peeps, I need your thoughts on a problem I ran into.

Is there anyway to restrict access to a list, but still allow all users to start a new workflow based off of that list?

I'm doing an approval workflow, and it works, but users do not need to see the approval status that is on the list.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is the workflow platform 2010 / 2013 ?

Comment: We are using 2013.

Comment: Your workflow is trigger when user add any item, but the workflow status column that shows current status , you want to hide that column from users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because list and workflow permissions can be challenging to manage, I've tended to create processes using *multiple* lists.  Users, for example, can kick off the workflow on one list, but process/approval is handled in a separate list that the users do not have access to.  The workflow uses elevated permissions to create/modify the approval list, and also creates links between items across the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform, you can use **app step** to allow access objects in SharePoint that require elevated permissions.

[image]

For more details check

- [Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx)
- [APP STEP IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013?](http://summit7systems.com/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)